# What is the most mature and maintained Markdown processor?

Tags: html, unix, markdown

I need to Process Markdown at the command line, so there is no real language restriction.

Extra features such as pretty quotes and dashes are a welcome addition. Code blocks are a must, but they are part of the core I think.

I want to output to HTML only, and I'm on a Unix environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using python with http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/ without any problem so far, and it has a simple extension mechanism.

Answer (score 25):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html) allows you convert Markdown to HTML (and *back*!) and [much more](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demos.html).

Comment: Excellent doc, imho some of the best anywhere (maturity alone is just old age)

Answer (score 11):

```
$ pandoc --help
pandoc [OPTIONS] [FILES]
Input formats:  
       native, json, markdown, markdown+lhs, rst, rst+lhs, 
       textile, html, latex, latex+lhs
Output formats:  
      native, json, html, html+lhs, s5, slidy, docbook, 
      opendocument, latex, latex+lhs, context, texinfo, 
      man, markdown, markdown+lhs, plain, rst, rst+lhs, 
      mediawiki, textile, rtf, org, odt, epub
Options:
  -f FORMAT, -r FORMAT  --from=FORMAT, --read=FORMAT                    
  -t FORMAT, -w FORMAT  --to=FORMAT, --write=FORMAT                     
  -s                    --standalone                                    
  -o FILENAME           --output=FILENAME                               
  -p                    --preserve-tabs                                 
                        --tab-stop=NUMBER                               
                        --strict                                        
                        --normalize                                     
                        --reference-links                               
  -R                    --parse-raw                                     
  -S                    --smart                                         
  -5                    --html5                                         
  -m[URL]               --latexmathml[=URL], --asciimathml[=URL]        
                        --mathml[=URL]                                  
                        --mimetex[=URL]                                 
                        --webtex[=URL]                                  
                        --jsmath[=URL]                                  
                        --mathjax[=URL]                                 
                        --gladtex                                       
  -i                    --incremental                                   
                        --offline                                       
                        --xetex                                         
                        --chapters                                      
  -N                    --number-sections                               
                        --listings                                      
                        --section-divs                                  
                        --no-wrap                                       
                        --columns=NUMBER                                
                        --ascii                                         
                        --email-obfuscation=none|javascript|references  
                        --id-prefix=STRING                              
                        --indented-code-classes=STRING                  
                        --toc, --table-of-contents                      
                        --base-header-level=NUMBER                      
                        --template=FILENAME                             
  -V KEY:VALUE          --variable=KEY:VALUE                            
  -c URL                --css=URL                                       
  -H FILENAME           --include-in-header=FILENAME                    
  -B FILENAME           --include-before-body=FILENAME                  
  -A FILENAME           --include-after-body=FILENAME                   
  -T STRING             --title-prefix=STRING                           
                        --reference-odt=FILENAME                        
                        --epub-stylesheet=FILENAME                      
                        --epub-cover-image=FILENAME                     
                        --epub-metadata=FILENAME                        
  -D FORMAT             --print-default-template=FORMAT                 
                        --bibliography=FILENAME                         
                        --csl=FILENAME                                  
                        --natbib                                        
                        --biblatex                                      
                        --data-dir=DIRECTORY                            
                        --dump-args                                     
                        --ignore-args                                   
  -v                    --version                                       
  -h                    --help
```

---

```
$ pandoc --version
pandoc 1.8.2

Compiled with citeproc support.

Compiled with syntax highlighting support for:

Actionscript, Ada, Alert, Alert_indent, Ansys, Apache, 
Asn1, Asp, Awk, Bash, Bibtex, Boo, C, Changelog, Cisco, 
Cmake, Coffeescript, Coldfusion, Commonlisp, Cpp, Cs, 
Css, Cue, D, Desktop, Diff, Djangotemplate, Doxygen, 
Doxygenlua, Dtd, Eiffel, Email, Erlang, Fortran, Fsharp, 
Fstab, Gap, Gdb, Gettext, Gnuassembler, Go, Haskell, 
Haxe, Html, Idl, Ilerpg, Ini, Java, Javadoc, Javascript, 
Json, Jsp, Latex, Lex, LiterateHaskell, Lua, M3u,  
Makefile, Mandoc, Matlab, Maxima, Mediawiki, Metafont, 
Mips, Modula2, Modula3, Monobasic, Nasm, Noweb, 
Objectivec, Objectivecpp, Ocaml, Octave, Pango, Pascal, 
Perl, Php, Pike, Postscript, Prolog, Python, R, 
Relaxngcompact, Rhtml, Ruby, Scala, Scheme, Sci, Sed, 
Sgml, Sql, SqlMysql, SqlPostgresql, Tcl, Texinfo, 
Verilog, Vhdl, Winehq, Wml, Xharbour, Xml, Xorg, Xslt, 
Xul, Yacc, Yaml
Copyright (C) 2006-2011
```

Answer (score 4):

There's also Discount, David Parsons' C implementation of John Gruber's Markdown text to html language. Discount consists of several command-line tools including `markdown`, `mkd2html`, `makepage`, `mktags` and `theme`.

http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/

Answer (score 4):

Also recommend Pandoc with below benefit:

1. code syntax highlighting in pandoc markdown is great for html, and it is growing !
2. pandoc markdown support is similar to github flavored markdown
3. more output format besides html, which probably you need in later like ebook

It is powerful!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the *most* maintained is, and I'm certainly biased by using it here most, but the one SO uses is also available on github, it's [the markdownsharp project](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/), written in C# and pretty well maintained.

It fixes many of the bugs in the original markdown implementation, found by SO users as questions were asked, like most things, just a project that came out of a necessity.  That being said, some of how markdown works is *as designed* per the spec, but isn't necessarily intuitive, it's the maintainers prerogative there as to what action to take there, intuitive vs spec...so you may have to adjust any implementation a bit to get *exactly* what you want in some edge cases.

Comment: Does it include a bin for use on a shell? Also... Can it run on Unix?

Comment: @Pepijn - The download is source only, but you can compile it as long as you have .Net 4 installed (which you'd have to have to run the console app anyway), not sure if this is an option for you or not...just answering in the "no language restriction" context of the question :)  A better approach IMO would be to include the project beside your console one...so you can more easily apply updates that come along.

Comment: So that would at least mean Mono for me. It might be a good option for others though, so I'll give you an upvote but not /my/ accepted solution.

Comment: @Pepijn - Fair enough :) I'd edit the question though, give a bit more information about the target environment, this will help get you better answers :)

Comment: Done. Only one other answer so far though.